# Is it possible to restrict access to attributes or items of a table in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I want to restrict access to a table using MongoDB like I do in DynamoDB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html

I mean that if I have a employee table that stores the NAME and INCOME, I want a role to restrict access to the INCOME attribute for some users. Also, I want another role that the user will be able to see the NAME and INCOME, but only if it matches a specific condition.

It is not clear if this is possible reading the official MongoDB documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Comment: Roles are currently not that granular. The general wisdom here is you build it yourself. Plus MongoDB is "schemaless" so by definition there is no actual schema stored to use as a "role restriction" guide. Apples and Oranges here really.

Comment: Neil's right that the current role- and privilege-based security model don't extend to document-level security restrictions. There is, however, the $redact aggregation pipeline stage that allows you to restrict the content of documents based on information stored in the document. You can find explanation and examples in the [$redact docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/).